# What is precisely the role of the '&' character in a bash/shell redirection?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, syntax

So as I'm writing my own shell for school, I have to implement redirections.

I've looked at the GNU Bash manual, and a fair amount of tutorials, but I'm still having troubles understanding *what exactly means the ampersand* in these redirections.
I know when I have to use them when using simple redirections, like `&>file` or `2>&-` but I don't get the precise meaning of it.

Could someone explain?

Comment: That's just the character used to specify the action.  What more are you looking for?  Why not ask what does the `>` mean or what does `|` mean or why was `$` chosen?  Additionally `&>` is sort of a non-standard redirection.

Comment: @jesse_b it's the action that I don't understand. I'm gonna have a look at that thread, thanks.

Comment: Do you know what the _rough_ meaning of it is? Do you know what stdout and stderr are? Is there something in specific that you're missing about the ampersand?

Comment: Your mistake is to separate the `&` from the `>`. Just like in C or javascript the `!=` operator is not `!` and `=` but just `!=`, so it's `>&` or `<&` in the shell language. All those operators are explained in the bash manpage, including the fact that `[n]>&-` is identical to `[n]<&-`, and `[n]>&n` is identical to `[n]<&n` (where `n` is a number), but `>& path` is something completely different than `>&n` (where `path` is NOT a number).

Answer (score 0):

The ampersand in `>&` does not have a functional role. Its role is more like the role of the letter c in `cat`.

The notations `>&`, `<&` etc have the roles explained in the man page for `bash`.

You could regard the `&` as indicating that the redirection involves merging two IO streams. But it is more of part of a mnemonic spelling choice, not a separate, independent per-character action or role.

The meta character `&` also occurs in other contexts as `&` at end of line or in the `&&` operator. But this is a bit like `c` appearing in both `cat` and `cd`. It is a common element in the spelling of several unrelated features.

Comment: Though the "merging" here is just the same as with `> $path 2> $path`, that is, a following redirection can still "unmerge" them